# How can I "roll up" values into subsequent records?

Tags: r

I have a data set (x) that looks like this:

```
        DATE  WEEKDAY      A          B           C            D
 2011-02-04   Friday      113        67         109           72
 2011-02-05 Saturday        1         0           0            1
 2011-02-06   Sunday        9         5           0            0
 2011-02-07   Monday      154        48          85           60
```

str(x):

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ DATE   : Date, format: "2011-02-04" "2011-02-05" "2011-02-06" "2011-02-07"
 $ WEEKDAY: Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 1 3 4 2
 $ A      : num  113 1 9 154
 $ B      : num  67 0 5 48
 $ C      : num  109 0 0 85
 $ D      : num  72 1 0 60
```

Tuesday - Saturday values don't change, but I want Sunday to be the sum of Saturday and Sunday and Monday to be the sum of Saturday, Sunday, and Monday.

I tried shifting Saturday's and Sunday's dates to date + 2 and date + 1 respectively, then aggregating by date, but I lose the weekend records.

For my example, the correct results would be the following:

```
        DATE  WEEKDAY      A          B           C            D
 2011-02-04   Friday      113        67         109           72
 2011-02-05 Saturday        1         0           0            1
 2011-02-06   Sunday       10         5           0            1
 2011-02-07   Monday      164        53          85           61
```

**How can I roll up weekend values into the next day?**

Three weeks' worth of data:

```
         DATE   WEEKDAY   A   B   C   D
1  2011-01-02    Sunday   2   1   0   0
2  2011-01-03    Monday 153  51   7   1
3  2011-01-04   Tuesday 182 103  13   5
4  2011-01-05 Wednesday 192 102  14  12
5  2011-01-06  Thursday 160  67  50  20
6  2011-01-07    Friday 154  96  50  39
7  2011-01-09    Sunday   0   0   0   1
8  2011-01-10    Monday 195  94  48  39
9  2011-01-11   Tuesday 206  72  71  38
10 2011-01-12 Wednesday 232  94  96  52
11 2011-01-13  Thursday 178 113  93  52
12 2011-01-14    Friday 173  97  68  56
13 2011-01-15  Saturday   2   0   1   0
14 2011-01-17    Monday 170  91  66  52
15 2011-01-18   Tuesday 176  76  70  78
16 2011-01-19 Wednesday 164 159 117  37
17 2011-01-20  Thursday 198  87  95 111
18 2011-01-21    Friday 213  86  89  90
19 2011-01-24    Monday 195  73 102  52
20 2011-01-25   Tuesday 193 108 116  70
21 2011-01-26 Wednesday 193 102 118  63
```

Comment: How about just: `df[2:4, 3:6] <- cumsum(df[2:4, 3:6])`?

Comment: I may need something more general -- the real data set has several years' worth of data and it's really the weekends that matter.

Comment: Post a longer example set. This one does not accurately represent the problem.

Comment: I added three weeks' worth of data, if that helps.

Comment: It helps to show that your data has gaps and starts on a Sunday which introduces problems for my solution. As I said your original did not illustrate the problem adequately.

Comment: @outis, I've made the code more compact and relatively more straightforward. You may want to have a look at it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've provided a small data, I've not been able to test this on a bigger data. But the idea is something like this. I'll use `data.table` as I find it can be very efficient here.

#### The code:

```
require(data.table) 
my_days <- c("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday")
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, `:=`(DATE = as.Date(DATE))]
setkey(dt, "DATE")
dt[WEEKDAY %in% my_days, `:=`(A = cumsum(A), B = cumsum(B), 
            C = cumsum(C), D = cumsum(D)), by = format(DATE-1, "%W")]
```

#### The idea:

- First, change the `DATE` Column to actual `Date` type using `as.Date` (line 4).
- Second, ensure that the columns are sorted by `DATE` column by setting the key column of `dt` to `DATE` (line 5).
- Now, the last line (line 6) is where all the magic happens and is the trickiest:

  - The first part of the expression `WEEKDAY %in% my_days,` subsets the `data.table` dt with only days = `Sat, Sun or Mon`.
  - The last part of the same line `by = format(DATE-1, "%W")`, subsets the data by the week they belong to. Here, since `Monday` falls on the next week, just subtract 1 from the *current Date* and then get the week number. This will group the Dates by `Week`, where, Tuesday until Monday should have the same week.
  - The expression in the middle `':='(A = ... , D = ...)` computes the `cumsum` and replaces just those values per grouping by reference.

---

For the new data you've posted, I get this as the result. Let me know if it's *not* what you seek.

```
#           DATE   WEEKDAY   A   B   C   D
#  1: 2011-01-02    Sunday   2   1   0   0
#  2: 2011-01-03    Monday 155  52   7   1
#  3: 2011-01-04   Tuesday 182 103  13   5
#  4: 2011-01-05 Wednesday 192 102  14  12
#  5: 2011-01-06  Thursday 160  67  50  20
#  6: 2011-01-07    Friday 154  96  50  39
#  7: 2011-01-09    Sunday   0   0   0   1
#  8: 2011-01-10    Monday 195  94  48  40
#  9: 2011-01-11   Tuesday 206  72  71  38
# 10: 2011-01-12 Wednesday 232  94  96  52
# 11: 2011-01-13  Thursday 178 113  93  52
# 12: 2011-01-14    Friday 173  97  68  56
# 13: 2011-01-15  Saturday   2   0   1   0
# 14: 2011-01-17    Monday 172  91  67  52
# 15: 2011-01-18   Tuesday 176  76  70  78
# 16: 2011-01-19 Wednesday 164 159 117  37
# 17: 2011-01-20  Thursday 198  87  95 111
# 18: 2011-01-21    Friday 213  86  89  90
# 19: 2011-01-24    Monday 195  73 102  52
# 20: 2011-01-25   Tuesday 193 108 116  70
# 21: 2011-01-26 Wednesday 193 102 118  63
#           DATE   WEEKDAY   A   B   C   D
```